# Numeric ID to very short unique strings

Tags: python, rust, hashids

I have rather long IDs `1000000000109872` and would like to represent them as strings.

However all the libraries for Rust I've found such as `hash_ids` and `block_id` produce strings that are way bigger.

Ideally I'd like 4 to maybe 5 characters, numbers are okay but only uppercase letters. Doesn't need to be cryptographically secure as long as it's unique.

Is there anything that fits my needs?

---

I've tried this website: https://v2.cryptii.com/decimal/base64 and for `1000000000109872` I get `4rSw`, this is very short which is great. But it's not uppercase.

Comment: what about using the methods that create long strings and taking only the first (or last) n characters?

Comment: You could just uppercase the base64 encoding you get.  Naturally there will be collisions, but given your constraints that's inevitable.

Comment: Base64 are numbers, uppercase and lowercase letteres plus '+' and '/'. Try Base32 instead, there you'll have only numbers and uppercase letters.

Comment: @Samwise Thought of doing that but the collisions are a problem

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki There's no way to rule out collisions that way

Comment: @jps Base32 is way too long `SDFQICGB9G`

Comment: Are the IDs arbitrarily long, while the hash you're trying to produce is arbitrarily short?  Or are you just trying to crunch the ID down as far as you can (within those character constraints) without any collisions?

Comment: 1000000000109872 looks suspicious, did you start at 1000000000000000?

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah

Comment: @Nikk It's a question of information content. You want it to be lossless (meaning, you can convert it back to the original string and no collisions exist), in computer science terms, you talk about "bits of information". A normal digit (from 0 to 9) contains ~3.3 bits of information (`log2(10)`). A digit + uppercase letter (36 possibilities) carries ~5.1 bits of information (`log2(36)`). Your original string is 16 digits, meaning `16*3.3 = 52` bits of information. With A-Z&0-9 this can be represented by `52/5.1 = 10` characters. It will never become less than that.

Comment: @Nikk *"did you start at 1000000000000000"* - why?

Comment: @Finomnis Well the database sequence starts at 1, but then we add a checksum digit to the right, and then append the rest of the `0` to the left. Where `1` is for the document type which is needed by our software to identify the ID.

Comment: Well I guess you now have all kinds of knowledge here, I don't know what to add myself. The rest depends on your usecase.

Comment: @Finomnis The idea to subtract `1000000000000000` is actually not bad. However it doesn't solve the problem long-term as the string ID's will just get bigger with time.

Comment: @Nikk You have to decide. Either you have a long string or you have collisions. You can't store 20 eggs in a box of 10. Just ask yourself: How would you store an ID from 0 to 1000 in a single letter of the alphabet? You can't, because there are only 26. It's the same problem, just bigger. You can't represent something in an arbitrary small amount of data, it's just mathematically impossible.

Comment: Also, your base64 encoding in your example is incorrect, it does not actually yield the number you were trying to encode

Answer (score 4):

This is the absolute best you can do if you want to guarantee no collisions without having any specific guarantees on the range of the inputs beyond "unsigned int" *and* you want it to be stateless:

```
def base_36(n: int) -> str:
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise TypeError("Check out https://mypy.readthedocs.io/")
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("IDs must be non-negative")
    if n < 10:
        return str(n)
    if n < 36:
        return chr(n - 10 + ord('A'))
    return base_36(n // 36) + base_36(n % 36)

print(base_36(1000000000109872))  # 9UGXNOTWDS
```

If you're willing to avoid collisions by keeping track of id allocations, you can of course do much better:

```
ids: dict[int, int] = {}
def stateful_id(n: int) -> str:
    return base_36(ids.setdefault(n, len(ids)))

print(stateful_id(1000000000109872))  # 0
print(stateful_id(1000000000109454))  # 1
print(stateful_id(1000000000109872))  # 0
```

or if some parts of the ID can be safely truncated:

```
MAGIC_NUMBER = 1000000000000000
def truncated_id(n: int) -> str:
    if n < MAGIC_NUMBER:
        raise ValueError(f"IDs must be >= {MAGIC_NUMBER}")
    return base_36(n - MAGIC_NUMBER)

print(truncated_id(1000000000109872))  # 2CS0
```

Comment: Can `base_36` deal with negative numbers? (Potential attack vector, just making sure OP is aware)

Comment: The magic number approach is interesting. But it doesn't solve the problems long-term as ID get way bigger.

Comment: Can't have your cake and eat it, @Nikk.  :)  I think this answer lays out all the different tradeoffs between constraining your inputs, keeping state, or having a longer output than you want.  The other possible tradeoff (not covered here because you already rejected it) is hashing the information into a smaller space than can represent all the possibilities, and therefore opening the possibility of collisions.  Pick one.

Comment: @Samwise You're right! Regarding the hashing method, what would be the best way to get the smallest string uppercase and numbers? Again doesn't need to be cryptographically secure as it's not going to be used in urls or anything.

Comment: The "smallest string" would be an empty string, which would also have 100% collisions.

Comment: You can squeeze an arbitrarily large int `n` into an arbitrary number of base-36 digits by taking its value mod 36 ** digits, e.g. `base_36(n % (36 ** 5))` to cap it at five digits, which also means you're accepting the possibility of collision for inputs greater than `36 ** 5`.

Comment: @Nikk I think it's all a question of usecase for your base36 strings. What will you use them for?

Comment: @Nikk I'm not sure what you mean with "cryptographically secure" - base36 isn't secure in any way, you can easily convert them back to the original. But they are unique and without collisions. And if you want to keep those requirements, the magic number approach is best you can get, I can prove to you that nothing more compact exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**: Impossible.

**Long Answer**: You're asking to represent `10^16` digits in `36^5` (5 uppercase chars).

Actually, an uppercase/number char would be a one of `36` cases (`10` numbers + `26` chars). But, `36^5 = 60,466,176` is less than `10^9`, which wouldn't work.

Since `36^10 < 10^16 < 36^11`, you'll need at least `11` uppercase chars to represent your (`10^16`) long IDs.

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated that there is even a checksum inside the original ID, I assume the new representation should contain all of its data.

In this case, your question is strongly related to [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) and [information content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_content).

Information content says that every data contains a certain amount of information. Information can be measured in bits.

The sad news is that now matter what, you cannot magically reduce your data to less bits. It will always keep the same amount of bits. You can just change the representation to store those bits as compact as possible, but you cannot reduce the number.

You might think of `jpg` or compressed movies, that are stored very compact; the problem there is they are lossy. They discard information not perceived by the human eye/ear and just delete them.

In your case, there is no trickery possible. You will always have a smallest and a largest ID that you handed out. And all the IDs between your smallest and largest ID have to be distinguishable.

Now some math. If you know the amount of possible states of your data (e.g. the amount of distinguishable IDs), you can compute the required information content like this: `log2(N)`, where `N` is the number of possible states.

So let's say you have 1000000 different IDs, that would mean you need `log2(1000000) = 19.93` bits to represent those IDs. You will never be able to reduce this number to anything less.

Now to actually represent them: You say you want to store them in in a string of 26 different uppercase letters or 10 different digits. This is called a [base36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) encoding.

Each digit of this can carry `log2(36) = 5.17` bits of information. Therefore, to store your 1000000 different IDs, you need at least `19.93/5.17 = 3.85` digits.

This is exactly what @Samwise's answer shows you. His answer is the mathematically most optimal way to encode this. You will never get better than his answer. And the amount if digits will always grow if the amount of possible IDs you want to represent grows. There's just no mathematical way around that.